# Pandas DataFrame Float64 - Point Precision

Tags: python, dataframe

Precisely, I have an Excel file that among other columns, I have one with float numbers.

**The problem is**: when trying to convert it´s values to string, Pandas looses the precision point number for some of them.

The flow is described below:

**Action - Reading Data:**

```
df = pd.read_excel(io=_file, sheet_name="History", header=4, skiprows=[5, 6, 7]).fillna("")
```

**Action - Converting:**

```
test = df.assign(STRING_VALUES=df.SOURCE_VALUES.map(lambda x: str(x)))
```

**Action - Checking Pandas Decimal Pattern:**

```
pd.get_option("styler.format.decimal")
```

Result: ',' (that´s correct).

**Action - The Reality**

[image]

**Highlights:**

*My job is: check if SOURCE_VALUES has more than two decimals values! And with this behavior, I am getting FALSE/POSITIVE reports.*

I am in Brazil, so we use the same format for (currency) float numbers as European does, thousands it is "." and for decimal ",". Apparently, the default format presented by Pandas is correct.

**Conclusion:**

As described in my image, not all values loose the precision point number. What s the workaround for this behavior?

**Conclusion 2:**

I got the real source file now in XML! And when I received the spreadsheet, it was no longer in that format, but in xlsx. In this way, Excel applied a standard format by creating a mask as usual for floating numbers.

For this reason I was intrigued, what would be the reason for some values to have the correct formatting and others not in the decimals after converting them to string.

But now, I am sure that it´s not a fault of Pandas. And the real values are "correct".

**Final Thoughts**

The most important lesson here is to be aware of the origin of the data, so that you don't mistrust your results!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like values in excel are formatted to display 0.00 format, but real data is different. For example, if you change format of value 4556.38 to display more digits, you will see 456.379999... . With that, pandas are reading the real value, not formatted value.

To control float to str conversion format, maybe use format method (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your attention and time! So, are you stating that e.g: the value of 4556.379999999999 when converted to string, it is in fact, the real data? And that only can be seen when converted to string but not in float64 format? I am not sure of this, because, as I stated above, I need to find deviations in values andnot formatting them instead. I need to validate as it is.

Comment: Try lambda this:  test = df.assign(STRING_VALUES=df.SOURCE_VALUES.map(lambda x:f'{x:.2f}' ))

Comment: Thanks for your response. My aim here with this post is to be sure that "the deviation values" (the long decimal numbers) are not wrong. But the data as it is. I cannot change or format (manipulating) the values, got it? Because I need to validate them, not treat them. After my last response to you, I got the base in XML and those long decimal numbers where there, so, PANDAS IS GETTING RIGHT WITHOUT ANY EXCEL FORMAT. That´s what I am looking for!